# How to assign 1 animation to multiple objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to initiate the movement of two cars in Unity. There will be a variable time gap between the time points which the two cars start moving. But Unity lets me assign only one animation at a time which means that I can not move the second car while the first animation is running.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Give them each there own AnimationController with a shared animation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer giving more specific explanations? I am quite new to this. Would really appreciate!

Comment: Each Car in your case will have an `Animator` component on it which you can attach an `AnimationController` too and in those `AnimationController`s you assign which animations belong to the `GameObject`.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimatorController.html